# Shared preferences "bypass default value"?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

So I have a few different checkboxes in my app and I'm changing their texts with the click of a button. What I'm trying to do is to save those strings in Shared Preferences but I have one problem. When creating shared preferences I have to enter a default value, but I already did set a default value in XML file, and I have too many checkboxes to set a default value for every single one of them. So my question is: is there a way to "bypass" this default value? This is my code so far:

```
private String getItemQuantity(String key){
    SharedPreferences itemQuantitySP = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return itemQuantitySP.getItemQuantitySP(key, );
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your default values into constants to ie. const.java file, then instead of putting default values in XML files set initial value in Activity onCreate using shared preference value. Of course read your shared preference value using default values from const.java.